# What does pandas' sub operator do?

Tags: python, pandas

This is coming straight from the tutorial, which I can't understand even after reading the doc.

```
In [14]: df = DataFrame({'one' : Series(randn(3), index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
   ....:                 'two' : Series(randn(4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
   ....:                 'three' : Series(randn(3), index=['b', 'c', 'd'])})
   ....: 

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
        one     three       two
a -0.626544       NaN -0.351587
b -0.138894 -0.177289  1.136249
c  0.011617  0.462215 -0.448789
d       NaN  1.124472 -1.101558

In [16]: row = df.ix[1]

In [17]: column = df['two']

In [18]: df.sub(row, axis='columns')
Out[18]: 
        one     three       two
a -0.487650       NaN -1.487837
b  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
c  0.150512  0.639504 -1.585038
d       NaN  1.301762 -2.237808
```

Why does the second row turn into 0? Is it being `sub`-stituted with 0?

Also, when I use `row = df.ix[0]`, the entire second column turns into `NaN`. Why?

Comment: Aside: `.iloc` is now preferred when you want to refer to a row or column by position and not index; it has simpler semantics.

Comment: Unclear why this has been downvoted, seems perfectly formed question to me

Comment: Indeed, I opened an issue so the docstring will be improved: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10093

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html#pandas.DataFrame.sub) means subtract, so lets walk through this:

```
In [44]:
# create some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
                    'two' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
                    'three' : pd.Series(np.random.randn(3), index=['b', 'c', 'd'])})
df
Out[44]:
        one     three       two
a -1.536737       NaN  1.537104
b  1.486947 -0.429089 -0.227643
c  0.219609 -0.178037 -1.118345
d       NaN  1.254126 -0.380208
In [45]:
# take a copy of 2nd row
row = df.ix[1]
row
Out[45]:
one      1.486947
three   -0.429089
two     -0.227643
Name: b, dtype: float64
In [46]:
# now subtract the 2nd row row-wise
df.sub(row, axis='columns')
Out[46]:
        one     three       two
a -3.023684       NaN  1.764747
b  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
c -1.267338  0.251052 -0.890702
d       NaN  1.683215 -0.152565
```

So probably what is confusing you is what is happening when you specified 'columns' as the axis to operate on. We've subtracted from each row the value of the 2nd row, this explains why the 2nd row has now become all 0's. The data you've passed is a series and we're aligning on column's so in effect we're aligning against the column names which is why it's performed row-wise

```
In [47]:
# now take a copy of the first row
row = df.ix[0]
row
Out[47]:
one     -1.536737
three         NaN
two      1.537104
Name: a, dtype: float64
In [48]:
# perform the same op
df.sub(row, axis='columns')
Out[48]:
        one  three       two
a  0.000000    NaN  0.000000
b  3.023684    NaN -1.764747
c  1.756346    NaN -2.655449
d       NaN    NaN -1.917312
```

So why do we now have a column with all `NaN` values? It's because when you perform any operator function with a `NaN` then the result is a `NaN`

```
In [55]:

print(1 + np.NaN)
print(1 * np.NaN)
print(1 / np.NaN)
print(1 - np.NaN)
nan
nan
nan
nan
```

Comment: Great explanation of the `axis` option. The index of `row` is `one two three`, and we matching this index with the column index of `df`.

Comment: Yes this happens because we've passed a series `In [57]:

type(row)
Out[57]:
pandas.core.series.Series` so we're now instructing the function on what the index of this series represents, in this case it's the columns so the alignment is performed against the columns rather than the index values

Answer (score 2):

What that is doing is subtracting each value in the second row from all the values in its column.  That is, it takes the value at position `("b", "one")` and subtracts it from all the values in column "one"; it takes the value at position `("b", "two")` and subtracts it from all the values in column "two"; and it takes the value at poisiton `("b", "three")` and subtracts it from all the values in column "three".  So, for instance, the result in `("c", "one")` is `0.011617 - (-0.138894) = 0.150512`.  All values in row "b" are zero because that is the row you are subtracting, so in that row you subtract it from itself, giving zero.

As for the second part of your question, if you choose the first row, it contains a NaN.  The subtraction thus subtracts NaN from all values in the second column, which turns them all into NaN as well (since anything minus NaN is NaN).

Comment: Understanding that `sub` means `subtract` makes it instantly clear.

Comment: @Heisenberg: On the page where you got your example, it says "DataFrame has the methods add, sub, mul, div".  If that does not immediately tell you that `sub` means "subtract", I'm not sure what to say.